# How can I can aggregate by group over an aggregate in Tableau?

Tags: aggregate-functions, tableau-api

I'm trying to visualize the median profit as a proportion of sales for each day of the week. My data looks like this:

```
Date Category Profit Sales State
1/1  Book     3      6     NY
1/1  Toys     12     30    CA
1/2  Games    9      20    NY
1/2  Books    5      10    WA
```

I've created a calculated field "Profit_Prop" as `SUM([Profit])/SUM([Sales])`. I want to display the median daily value of profit_prop for Mondays, Tuesdays, etc.

I can kind of do this as a boxplot by adding `WEEKDAY(Date)` to Columns and Profit_Prop to Rows, then adding Date to Detail and changing granularity to Exact Date. But I just want to display the median without displaying a data point for each day.

I tried making another calculated field with `MEDIAN([Profit_prop])`, but I get "argument to MEDIAN is already an aggregation and cannot be further aggregated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove date from the level of detail.
Create calculated field like below and use it instead of Profit prop

```
median(
{ INCLUDE [Date]:
[Profit_Prop]
}
)
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This worked! I have no idea why though. I feel like I understand Tableau even less now...

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a calculation on a calculated field normal median function doesn't work instead you need to use the `Table calculations`.

Taking data from your example, create a formula. Use below code:

Create a calculated field and paste below code:

```
WINDOW_MEDIAN([Calculation1],FIRST(),LAST())
```

Set the computation to `Table Down`